# Exposing python daemon as a service

Tags: python, linux, unix, service, daemon

So, there are two very valuable features that I am already able to extract from a python script. The first is the ability to run a python function as a service from the command line. Assuming that the python script takes in command line args for simplicity. Something along the lines of:

```
import sys

def foo():
    return "%s is your last argument!" % sys.argv[-1]

foo()
```

which I would then access globally by running `python file.py somearg`and additionally, I could write up a supervisord script to daemonize a script and keep it running in memory. I now find myself in a position where I need both of these features at once and I'm not really sure where to start on this. For clarity, I basically have something along these lines:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    big_file = open(slow_loader)
    foo(big_file)
```

Where ideally, once this is running I would be keeping the entire `big_file` in memory and be able to access the `foo` method depending on that `big_file` by running something akin to the original `python file.py somearg`. I'm not really sure how to progress from here though.

Any help, even if it's just a link to some documentation would be very helpful. Ahead of time, I realized I could wrap this in a shallow flask app and run it through `http` requests, but for NDA'd reasons I need something that runs through an internal shell command.

Comment: Is introducing something like redis or memcached a possibility?

Comment: @dano I can totally add any external service, but not to replace the big_file. Technically I can't actually touch the source for for the `file.py`, but I'm confident enough in introspection that once the main solution is there I can apply it to this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because I like zmq and gevent, I would probably do something like this:

server.py

```
import gevent
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
import zmq.green as zmq
import json

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
socket.bind("ipc:///tmp/myapp.ipc")

def do_something(parsed):
    return sum(parsed.get("values"))

def handle(msg):
    data = msg[1]
    parsed = json.loads(data)
    total = do_something(parsed)
    msg[1] = json.dumps({"response": total})
    socket.send_multipart(msg)

def handle_zmq():
    while True:
        msg = socket.recv_multipart()
        gevent.spawn(handle, msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    handle_zmq()
```

And then you would have a client.py for your command line tool, like

```
import json
import zmq

request_data = {
        "values": [10, 20, 30 , 40],
        }

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
socket.connect("ipc:///tmp/myapp.ipc")
socket.send(json.dumps(request_data))
print socket.recv()
```

Obviously this is a contrived example, but you should get the idea.  Alternatively you could use something like xmlrpc or jsonrpc for this as well.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest using something-AMQP based, but ZeroMQ would work fine, too.

Comment: Sorry, any chance you could explain a little more explanation around the `gevent.spawn` and `gevent.monkey.patch_all` bits?

Comment: `gevent` is a `greenlet`-based asynchronous networking framework. That call is running `handle` in a greenlet, so that it can asynchronously handle `msg` while still listening for new requests. Note that it only makes the I/O asynchronous, though. It may or may not be useful to you, depending on what kind of work you're doing in your implementation of `handle` . If you're doing something that's CPU-bound, you'd probably want to use `multiprocessing` instead. And being asynchronous may not mean much at all if you're not expecting concurrent requests to come into `server.py`.